# Why is Pandas to_datetime is stripping nanoseconds with one format string, but not another?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am attempting to convert a timestamp with nanoseconds to a Pandas datetime object via `pandas.to_datetime`.

The following does what I expect:

```
print(pandas.to_datetime('2023-01-02 03:04:05.012345678', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
> 2023-01-02 03:04:05.012345678
```

However when I use the following slightly different time format, nanoseconds are stripped:

```
print(pandas.to_datetime('2023.01.02D03:04:05.012345678', format='%Y.%m.%dD%H:%M:%S.%f'))
> ValueError: unconverted data remains: 678
```

What is the cause of this?

This is with Python v3.9.0, Pandas v1.5.0

Comment: I cannot replicate: `print(pd.to_datetime('2023.01.02D03:04:05.012345678', format='%Y.%m.%dD%H:%M:%S.%f'))` prints `2023-01-02 03:04:05.012345678`. I use pandas `1.5.2`

Comment: @AndrejKesely I just double checked to make sure I can reproduce, and I can.  This is with pandas 1.5.0

Comment: This was a bug ([GH48767](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/48767)) fixed in v1.5.1: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.5.1.html#fixed-regressions. Your best option is to update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this is a bug in Pandas ([GH48767](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/48767)) and appears to have been fixed in Pandas v1.5.1.

The bug ticket seems to indicate that this is a regression, so it likely effects some but not all earlier versions.